Consultation on password synchronization between ubuntu 22.04 system user password and samba user
How to automatically update the password of a samba user after changing the password of a common user in the ubuntu system？
I use openldap as the backend database.
The password of the samba user is automatically updated after the password is changed by running the passwd command
